# getting an error "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" while executing below piece of code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
i='etl_id'  # i is dynamic here sometime 'claim_number'
flt = df1['_merge'] == 'left'
ls = list(df1[i].where(flt))
df2 = df2[~df2.i.isin(ls)]
```

Here I am trying to drop an entire row from dataframe2 based on list of etl_ids or claim_number (*which I have got from dataframe1*)
But getting an error in last line: "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"
Or if in case any other alternative way to write this code would help here?

Comment: Which line fails? Please post a traceback so we can see. Likely you have an unexpected `None` (maybe in `i`). You could print values or even add an `assert` or two while you find out. Then its a question of testing for that case and do whatever you think is appropriate.

Comment: It is getting fails on last line. Yes I can understand the scenarios, even though "i" is not None getting this error. Thanks for response

Comment: This kind of errors mean that you probably trying to unpack object that doesn't exist, maybe you are getting df2 in wrong type, or df2.i is returning None or something like this, try to check df2 for these problems